# Modelling Poisson Overdispersion In Timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp, poisson

I am trying to modelling timestamps of events which usually conform to a Poisson process, where mean = variance. I've achieved this using the following code which samples from an exponential (the inter time count is exponential for Poisson) and it seems to work fairly well.

```
    def GenerateTimes(self):

        intervals = [random.expovariate(self.CountsPerSecond) for i in range(self.nDataPoints)]
        timeStamps = [0.0]
        timeStamp = 0.0

        for t in intervals:
            timeStamp += t
            timeStamps.append(timeStamp)

        self.timeStamps = timeStamps
```

I now want to model a very similar process and include a degree of overdispersion i.e. variance > mean. For a full explanation of overdispersion look at 
[this page](http://biometry.github.io/APES//LectureNotes/2016-JAGS/Overdispersion/OverdispersionJAGS.html). Essentially I want to include a degree of 'clumping' or 'clustering' in the time stamps.

Ideally I'd like the mean to be the same as the pure Poisson process but the standard deviation to be increased by a multiplier i.e. 1.5 x sigma, 2 x sigma etc. Any advice on how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially I need a version of expovariate which allows for overdispersion. Will the negative binomial do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a Cox Point Process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process

In a Cox point process there is clustering of the events and hence greater variance than in a Poisson point process.

Comment: Great! Any idea how you generate pseudo random time stamps in Python  according to the Cox Point Process?

Comment: Sorry I don't have Python code for you, but it is a doubly stochastic process where the time stamp events will vary as a Poisson distribution, where its rate parameter also varies according to some distribution. Another way of saying it is that the intensity of the Poisson point process' rate is variable. There are different types of Cox point processes, with the Log Gaussian Cox process being the most common. This link does some good explanation including examples: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/doubly-stochastic-poisson-process.